# What is meant by "n/m score" and "p/q answers" in profile activity page in Summary box?

Tags: support, profile-page, reputation-graph

In my profile activity page I see

[image: Summary information from user profile activity page]

What is the meaning of those (fractional) numbers at bottom centre

(and how do the progress bars under them relate to the values)

Comment: I see. It would have been clearer to me if the badge name and the progress bars were both grouped (e.g. in a group box) under a "NEXT TAG BADGE" heading more like the "REPUTATION" heading.  @vandench: yes - please post your comment as  an answer.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick sounds like a fair feature request, you can start a new question asking for it. :)

Comment: Considering how much horizontal space is available, using a potentially confusing short form like this seems pointless.

Comment: This is exacerbated by the odd grouping of the information; it is not clear if the progress meters apply to the tracked badge, or to someting in the rep graph, or some third thing. Perhaps it would be better to put the badge tracking outside the "Summary" box (which could then have a more specific label, too) or in its own "Badge Progress" box.

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack [done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391366/282212)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears to be tracking the <kbd>[router](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/router)</kbd> tag bronze badge.

You have 99 out of the 100 required score for the bronze badge, and have already passed the 20 required answers.

The exact [requirements](https://superuser.com/help/badges/152/router) are described as

> Earn at least 100 total score for at least 20 non-community wiki answers in the <kbd>router</kbd> tag.

Answer (score 8):

To earn the bronze tag badge for "router" you need to have a sum of 100 score (upvotes minus downvotes) on answers to questions that have that tag, and you need to have 20 answers to questions that have that tag. See:

[What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for#68395)

The denominators (m and q) are the requirements to earn the badge. The numerators (n and p) are your stats towards those requirements.

You have enough total answers already: you've answered 43 questions tagged "router" out of 20 required for the badge.

You don't have quite enough score (upvotes minus downvotes) on answers of questions tagged "router": you have 99 out of 100 required.

One more net upvote, whether on an old or new answer, will be enough to earn you that tag badge.

You can click the little "gear" icon to see other tags you've made progress to, and select a different tag to "track" if you don't like the one that was chosen automatically by the system. I think the meaning is clearer on that page because you can see the different numbers clearly associated to different tag badges. It seems like it could be useful to group the tag badge information together and separate it from the other general "reputation" info since it's otherwise not particularly clear that the ratios on the right relate to the tag badge on the left.