# Improve readability of the "next badge" tracker

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, tag-badges, badge-progress

In [What is meant by "n/m score" and "p/q answers" in profile activity page in Summary box?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391329/282212) I asked about the meaning of the "n/m score" and "p/q answers" items in the Activity page of a user's Profile.

[image: User Profile Reputation information box]

There are some suggestions for making it clearer what these mean. Mainly making it clear that they measure progress against the "next badge" to the left and are not directly measuring the "REPUTATION" shown above them in the same box.

Answer (score 7):

This is my suggestion:

[image: next tag badge appearing inside the Badges widget]

If user choose to track tag badge, put it inside the "Badges" widget itself.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

1. Give these items an equally prominent title, Change "Next tag badge" to "NEXT TAG BADGE" in the same font and size as the "REPUTATION" title

   Separate all the **badge progress** items either by

   1. A **horizontal line**  or
   2. An **inner box** containing them all and only them  or
   3. A **separate box** containing them all and only them

Comment: NEXT TAG BADGE is too noisy, more than one word in upper case is problematic. IMO better completely separate it.

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack: I'd be happy to support that, could you put it in an answer so that people can upvote it to express a preference?